# Rails security on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security

I am putting my first rails app on the internet, I have read the rails guide on security and have implemented the points listed in there but was interested to hear of anything else ?

Also I currently store my uploads in public/documents is this ok ? I noticed there is no htaccess files protecting the directory.

Comment: Thanks for awarding it to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Storing your uploads in a predictable location is a bad idea if you want to keep them a secret.  If you don't care about people accessing it then it doesn't matter. Using .htaccess to password protect the directory is a good solution.

You should test your application for vulnerablites using [Acunetx](http://www.acunetix.com/)($$) or [Wapiti](http://wapiti.sourceforge.net/) (open source).

You should also read: [What should a developer know before building a public web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site)

Answer (score 2):

If your site allows anyone to upload, it is a bad idea to store your uploads in a place that non-logged-in users can get to them.  This is because then your site can be used by unscrupulous people as a place to store things that you might not want stored, such as malware.